# Grabbing user:password individually

Tags: vb.net

I import login info file from .txt to TextBox1 and then, what I want to do is to use these login infos to log in to a website. So, I need to grab them line by line; and the structure is "user:password" like this.

How can I grab only "user" and then only "password" , ignoring ":" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Lines as String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path\to\file")
For Each Line as String in Lines
    Dim Credentials as String() = String.Split(Line,":",2)
    ' User will be Credentials(0), Password will be Credentials(1)
    ' Insert code to attempt login
End For
```

No additional textbox required.

Comment: Thank you for your help, may I ask where I'm going to write this code? I am a TOTAL newbie, sorry.

Comment: That is up to you. I'd suggest putting it behind a button or some other interactable control (if you're making a Windows Forms app). If you wanted to, you could also output the current username and password being attempted to the window.